# The simplest and most pythonic way to test if a variable is between two other variables?

Tags: python

I have two variables `n1` and `n2`, without knowing which is bigger. I want to test if `n` is between `n1` and `n2`.

While I can definitely test `if min(n1, n2) < n < max(n1, n2)`, I am just curious if there is any more pythonic way to do it.

I am thinking something like `if n in range(sorted(n1, n2))`, but this does not work because I can't put a list in `range( )`.

I also find there is `between()` function in `pandas`, but it is way too powerful than what I need.

Comment: `range(*sorted(n1, n2))`

Comment: Exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: That considers the left endpoint (i.e. `min(n1, n2)`) as part of the range though.

Comment: This is a good point and I didn't realize it, but it is acceptable in my case, thanks!

Comment: Does that mean you only care about "approximately between"? I.e., acceptable if wrong when n==n1 or n==n2?

Comment: `pythonic` means readability. If its not readable, its not pythonic.If you want smaller or more efficient code, that means somthing else.

Comment: @ Kelly Yes for my specific case, including the boundary or not does not make much difference.

Comment: @Nitish Isn't it easier to read and exactly follows my intention? I only want to see if ```n``` is between ```n1``` and ```n2```, and don't want to find the min and max of them.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it simple and check the two cases:

```
if n1 < n < n2 or n2 < n < n1:
```

To avoid typing them twice you can hide it in a function:

```
def is_between(n, n1, n2):
    return n1 < n < n2 or n2 < n < n1
```

```
if is_between(n, n1, n2):
```

It seems overcomplicated, but if you want to sort them you could do:

```
l, h = sorted([n1, n2])
if l < n < h:
```

Comment: I just wonder if there is a way I only need to type ```n1``` and ```n2``` once?

Comment: Anyway to do it in one line?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to take the differences between both sets and see if the product is negative:

```py
if (n1 - n) * (n2 - n) < 0:
    ...
```

The only way to get a negative result is if the 2 differences have opposite signs, which would only happen if n is bigger than one number and smaller than the other.

Comment: Thanks, this is a smart way but a bit ambiguous if someone else is reading your code without prior knowledge.

Comment: Cool trick, but IMHO too clever. Would be ok if you hide it in a function and document it.

Comment: It's also limited to numbers, whereas John's solution will work with anything for which `<` defines a total ordering. Still, neat mathematical trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n1 <= n) == (n < n2):
```

That's equivalent to the `n in range(*sorted([n1, n2]))` that you tried to write and said is ok.

Comment: Very clever. Note that if the numbers are floats NaN will trip it up.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Hmm, yeah, nans are nasty. I'm assuming "normal" values. The OP's attempt to use `range` even suggests they're ints.